# Add button with custom event in Filepond drop area

Tags: vuejs2, filepond

I want to add a button in drop area with custom event on it to trigger a modal.

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
       <file-pond
        name="test"
        ref="pond"
        max-files="4"
        label-idle="Drop files here... <button class=“Filepond—custom”>Search<\button>"
        :allow-multiple="true"
        accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
        :files="myFiles"
        v-on:init="handleFilePondInit"
        allowImagePreview ="false"
        />

    </div>
</template>
```

Is there a way to do this?

I tried creating a plug-in on CREATE_VIEW filter but I wasn’t successful.

Edit: The problem with CREATE_VIEW or any other available filter is that they all are applied when the item(s) is added/updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be another workaround but I came up with this solution.

On Filepond initalization I was able to append the button and attached an event to it.

```
handleFilePondInit: function () {
        // Filepond is initialized
        const element = document.querySelector('.filepond--label-action');

        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.type = 'button';
        button.className = 'filepond--media-search-action';
        button.innerHTML = 'Button Name'

        button.addEventListener('click', () => {console.log('button clicked')});

        element.appendChild(button);
},
```